# Difference in Sound Intensity Level Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to produce the following plot:

[image: Sound Intensity Level]

And here's mine (No labels, still just trying to get the plot right).
[image: My plot]

I can't seem to get a square grid, nor can I get the plot to start at -10dB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the (relevant part of the) code you used to draw this figure.

Comment: If you used `pgfplots`, you can use `axis equal` or `axis equal image` to get a square grid. But as it stands, we have no idea how you created the existing figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to use tikzpicture environment rather than axis and figured it out.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    % Domain
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,16}     
        \draw [black!30!white](\x,-11) -- (\x,13);
    % Range
    \foreach \y in {-11,-10,...,13} 
        \draw [black!30!white](0,\y) -- (16,\y);
    % x Axis
    \draw [-latex](0,0) -- (16,0);          
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,15}
        \draw (\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
    \foreach \x in {5,10,15}
        \draw (\x,0) node [below,inner sep=1pt,below=3pt,rectangle,fill=white]{\x};
    % x Axis
    \draw [latex-latex](0,-11) -- (0,13);       
    \foreach \y in {-9,-8,...,11}
        \draw (-0.1,\y)--(0.1,\y);
    \foreach \y in {-10,-5,0,5,10}
        \draw (0,\y) node [left]{\y};
    % Decibel
    \draw (0,13) node [above]{\textit{dB}};
    %P2/P1 Ratio
    \draw (16,0) node [right,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white]{\large $\frac{P_2}{P_1}$};
    % Plot function
    \draw[domain=0.08:16,samples=200,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{10*log10(\x)});
    % Trace lines
    \draw [fill=black,dashed] (0.1,-10)--(0.1,0) node [yshift=8pt,xshift=2pt]{\scalebox{0.7}{$\frac{1}{10}$}} circle (0.1);
    \draw [fill=black,dashed] (0.5,-3 )--(0.5,0) node [yshift=8pt,xshift=3pt]{\scalebox{0.7}{$\frac{1}{2}$}} circle (0.1);
    % Plot points
    \draw [blue,fill=blue](0.1,-10) circle (0.1) node   [black,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white,right=3pt]{One tenth power};
    \draw [blue,fill=blue](0.5,-3)  circle (0.1) node   [black,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white,right=7pt]{Half power};
    \draw [blue,fill=blue](1,0)     circle (0.1) node   [black,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white,right,xshift=5pt,yshift=10pt]{Equal power};
    \draw [blue,fill=blue](2,3)     circle (0.1) node   [black,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white,right=7pt]{Double power};
    \draw [blue,fill=blue](10,10)   circle (0.1) node   [black,inner sep=1pt,rectangle,fill=white,right,yshift=-8pt]{Tenfold power};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Difference in Sound Intensity Level}
\label{fig:sound_intensity_level}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also accept your own answer to mark this question as solved.